# Javascript and Ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript files that is suppose to interact with the response of my ajax request but apparently the javascript can't read the response from the ajax request.

What I'm asking is, how can I make my jquery plugin read the class in the response of my ajax request?

This is how my script looks without ajax:

```
 <body>
 <div id="main_content">

 <!--this is where the ajax is returning the info-->
 </div>
 </body>

 <body>
 <div id="main_event_saff">

 <!--this is an example of the ajax returns-->
   <table>
  <tbody>
<tr>
<td class="header">Header</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
<td class="data">Data</td>
</tr>
 </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
 </body>
```

Ajax file:

```
 $(document).ready( function rankings(callback){

 $.ajax({

   url: 'ajax/rankings.php',
   type: 'GET',
   success: function(response){

      $('#main_event_saff').html(response);

   }

 });

});
```

Here's the plugin that I want to read the response of the ajax request:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $(".data").hide();

$(".header").click(function () {
    $(this).next(".data").slideToggle(200);
});

});
```

This doesn't work because it can't read the ajax request

just like the page source it only see's

Comment: _"I make my jquery plugin"_  why not use `$.ajax()` from jquery library that work across cross browser?

Comment: Agreed, your already using jQuery, so I would use $.ajax() as well... otherwise you are just making it difficult

Comment: Could `main_event_saff` be incorrect spelling? Could it actually be `main_event_staff` or `main_content` ? If the ID is misspelled the update will fail.

Comment: @jogesh_pi I'm actually using jquer now

Comment: @mattchambers you are trying to sliding the `<td class="data">` right?

Comment: @jogesh_pi I'm trying to get that script by seeing <td class="data"> from the ajax request.

When I look on the source code, I only see <div id="main_event_saff"> and not the response

Comment: @mattchambers hows you checking the source code? through firebug? or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click event on dynamic element should work like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#main_event_saff").on('click', '.header',function () {
        $(this).next(".data").slideToggle(200);
    });

});
```

for more information take a look on the [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 2):

As you said you are using jQuery, why not this

```
  $(document).ready( function rankings(callback){
     $.ajax({
         url : 'ajax/rankings.php',
         type : 'GET',
         data : 'yourData',
         success : function(response){
           $('#main_event_saff').html(response);                
         }

     });
  });
```

this will make your work easy

Answer (score 2):

You can use simply [$.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) a jQuery ajax request:

```
$( "#main_event_saff" ).load( "ajax/rankings.php" );
```

You might want to do something more on getting the response :

```
$( "#main_event_saff" ).load( "ajax/rankings.php", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't used

```
id="main_event_staff"
```

in your HTML so how would you eventually read/write to its inner HTML.